# How to remove the Ctrl-Z in the file with dos batch

Tags: linux, batch-file, copy, dos, cat

I found that every time I concatenate all the files into one file with

```
copy *.txt all.txt
```

, there is a Ctrl-Z character at the end of the file. I don't want this character. Is there any way to write a batch script to remove this character or avoid this to happen?

What I wanted to do is

```
cat *.txt > all.txt
```

in linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
copy /b *.txt all.txt
```

For help, enter `help copy`.

Comment: You mean /B can avoid that character? I saw the manual and it says that /B is to indicate a binary file. What is that means? Why it can avoid this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why, but it works. I guess, a text file is also a binary file. Binary copy means `1:1` copy, no `EOF` appending.

Comment: the /b only flags the one file as binary, so "copy /b *.txt all.txt" means to open *.txt as binary files, and then put them into all.txt as a non-binary file. To make the destination binary as well, you would type "copy /b *.txt /b all.txt". Marcus, Binary means with control characters. Ascii files will have all non-printable character removed.

Answer (score 3):

In the CP/M days, filesizes were not recorded in bytes, but BLOCKS of 128 bytes. It was therefore necessary to assign an END-OF-FILE byte (^Z=1AH) to indicate a partially-filled textfile block (and no-EOF meant "exactly fills the last 128-byte bock")

This convention was honoured by MSDOS and its derivatives - and is why `COPY CON: filename` is terminated by a ^Z.

The `COPY` command allows the `^Z` to be interpreted differently - hence `/a` and `/b` modes, as demonstrated by the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: set COPYCMD=Y to auto-allow overwriting of destination
SET copycmd=Y
:: copy using FRED1.txt (no ^Z-terminal)
>NUL COPY /a fred1.txt freda1.txt
>NUL COPY fred1.txt fred1a.txt /a
>NUL COPY /b fred1.txt fredb1.txt
>NUL COPY fred1.txt fred1b.txt /b
>NUL COPY /a fred1.txt freda1a.txt /a
>NUL COPY /a fred1.txt freda1b.txt /b
>NUL COPY /b fred1.txt fredb1a.txt /a
>NUL COPY /b fred1.txt fredb1b.txt /b

DIR fred*1*|FIND /i "fred"
ECHO.

:: copy using FRED2.txt (has ^Z-terminal) to fred*2*
>NUL COPY /a fred1.txt fred2.txt
>NUL COPY /a fred2.txt freda2.txt
>NUL COPY fred2.txt fred2a.txt /a
>NUL COPY /b fred2.txt fredb2.txt
>NUL COPY fred2.txt fred2b.txt /b
>NUL COPY /a fred2.txt freda2a.txt /a
>NUL COPY /a fred2.txt freda2b.txt /b
>NUL COPY /b fred2.txt fredb2a.txt /a
>NUL COPY /b fred2.txt fredb2b.txt /b

DIR fred*2*|FIND /i "fred"
ECHO.

:: append-copy using FRED1.txt+FRED2.txt to fred*3*
>NUL COPY /a fred1.txt+fred2.txt freda3.txt
>NUL COPY fred1.txt+fred2.txt fred3a.txt /a
>NUL COPY /b fred1.txt+fred2.txt fredb3.txt
>NUL COPY fred1.txt+fred2.txt fred3b.txt /b
>NUL COPY /a fred1.txt+fred2.txt freda3a.txt /a
>NUL COPY /a fred1.txt+fred2.txt freda3b.txt /b
>NUL COPY /b fred1.txt+fred2.txt fredb3a.txt /a
>NUL COPY /b fred1.txt+fred2.txt fredb3b.txt /b

DIR fred*3*|FIND /i "fred"
ECHO.

:: append-copy using FRED2.txt+FRED2.txt to fred*4*
>NUL COPY /a fred2.txt+fred2.txt freda4.txt
>NUL COPY fred2.txt+fred2.txt fred4a.txt /a
>NUL COPY /b fred2.txt+fred2.txt fredb4.txt
>NUL COPY fred2.txt+fred2.txt fred4b.txt /b
>NUL COPY /a fred2.txt+fred2.txt freda4a.txt /a
>NUL COPY /a fred2.txt+fred2.txt freda4b.txt /b
>NUL COPY /b fred2.txt+fred2.txt fredb4a.txt /a
>NUL COPY /b fred2.txt+fred2.txt fredb4b.txt /b

DIR fred*4*|FIND /i "fred"
ECHO.

GOTO :EOF
```

Run result:

```
26/07/2013  08:51                 7 fred1.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 7 fred1a.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 7 fred1b.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 8 freda1.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 8 freda1a.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 7 freda1b.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 7 fredb1.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 7 fredb1a.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 7 fredb1b.txt

26/07/2013  08:51                 8 fred2.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 8 fred2a.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 8 fred2b.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 8 freda2.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 8 freda2a.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 7 freda2b.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 8 fredb2.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 8 fredb2a.txt
26/07/2013  08:51                 8 fredb2b.txt

26/07/2013  09:35                15 fred3a.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                14 fred3b.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                15 freda3.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                15 freda3a.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                14 freda3b.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                15 fredb3.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                16 fredb3a.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                15 fredb3b.txt

26/07/2013  09:35                15 fred4a.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                14 fred4b.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                15 freda4.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                15 freda4a.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                14 freda4b.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                16 fredb4.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                17 fredb4a.txt
26/07/2013  09:35                16 fredb4b.txt
```

Note how juxataposing `/a` and `/b` produces different results, all with various combinations of `^Z`-inclusion or even appended.

Note also that a simple `COPY` can fail if the source is a BINARY file and the `/b` switch is omitted. I've never investigated it, but I found it happens occasionally on copying `.MPG`s. I suspect that if `^Z` appears in the file before any byte >=80H then the file is assumed to be ASCII and hence terminated unceremoniously there and then - but as I say, I've not investigated it.